Cannot sent email as or on behalf of in Microsoft 365
I am unable to send an email either as or on behalf of a group mailbox. When I try to send via Outlook, I get an undeliverable message saying I don't have permission to send on behalf of this mailbox. I understand Outlook will try to send as first, then will default to on behalf of if that fails. I have not found a way to explicitly tell it to only send as. I have also tried to send via OWA.
Here is what I have tried:

I have granted myself the send as delegated permission


Waited (up to an hour)

Downloaded the offline address list

Ensure I have selected the address from the online address list



Tried using OWA


Tried adding Send on behalf of as well as a last resort, same result


